# How is padding from ascender/descender/normal letters done in HTML?

Tags: html, css

On our page we have 5px between the bottom of a letter "f", and 2px of padding below a letter "p." We are trying to figure out if padding-bottom: 5px; in the CSS should go from the bottom of the "f" or the bottom of the "p"

Thanks for the help, weird question!

Comment: just give the element a background color. Then you can see where it will start adding the padding. My guess is that it also depends on the font you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Padding-bottom generally extends below the descender of the text, i.e. it's additional space plus what would be there for the text alone.

It might also help to set line-height explicitly, so a value like 1.2. That will help make your results a lot more consistent across browsers, as line-height: normal really isn't. See [line-height: abnormal](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/) for more detailed discussion on that issue.

Comment: Absolutely. Padding doesn't apply to letters or lines, it applies to *elements*, usually `display: block` elements. Use `line-height:` -- great link too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

line-height should help you-
all the letters height should fit in the given line height-
for example:

```
.test
{
  font-size       : 50px;
  line-height     : 10px;
  padding-top     : 5px;
  padding-bottom  : 5px;
}

<div class="test">
  Hello Wquorld
</div>
```

this can't fit- so the complete height of the div is line-height + padding-top + padding-bottom (20px).
the text would overflow at top and bottom.

I have made a [quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/s_light/kHBsm/).
I always use the tool firebug (an extension for Firefox) it can show you paddings and margins from an element live.
Some more into the depth information you can find at w3.org:
10 Visual formatting model details -> 10.8 Line height calculations at the w3.org page.
Adress: w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height (no link because of spam prevention)